# react-i18next's Trans function have issue to interpolate correctly

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Got a very strange issue with `react-i18next's  Trans` function, the Interpolation does not work properly somehow.
Code that have issues:

`<Trans t={t} i18nKey={modal.header} tOptions={{ id }} />`

For some reason, It does not render `{{id}}` properly. In the below case, `{{id}}` should replace with `id1`

- For English locale: Delete id "{{id}}"?
- For Chinese locale: 删除编码 “{{id}}”？

**My observation:**

If I change code to not use Trans:

- It works well and rendering properly: Delete id "id1"?

`t(modal.header, { id })`

I understand the workaround is using t() rather than Trans function, However I would like to know what cause the issue. From [official documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component), all the props in Trans function is optional.

React version:"^17.0.2" , React-i18next: ^11.18.6

Comment: `tOptions={{ id }}` I think you want the `values` prop, not the `tOptions` prop